No code coverage attachments were found from the trx files on self hosted agent
I have setup a azure devops pipeline for the .net core 3.1.0 application , but not coverage files are being picked by sonarcloud. What could I be missing , this build is running a self hosted azure devops pipeline. Is there something else that is need to the agent where the build is running from?
 C:\agent\_work\_tasks\SonarCloudPrepare_14d9cde6-c1da-4d55-aa01-2965cd301255\2.2.0\classic-sonar-scanner-msbuild\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end
SonarScanner for MSBuild 6.2
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Post-processing started.
11:17:30.481  11:17:30.481  WARNING: File 'C:\agent\_work\1\s\Services\Internal\WebJob\WebJob_TemporaryKey.pfx' does not exist.
11:17:30.496  11:17:30.496  WARNING: File 'C:\agent\_work\1\s\Services\External\Api\Properties\PublishProfiles\vodacom-api-fs-sme-dev - Web Deploy.pubxml' does not exist.
11:17:30.496  11:17:30.496  WARNING: File 'C:\agent\_work\1\s\Tests\Functional\Helpers.Tests\libman.json' does not exist.
11:17:30.715  11:17:30.715  WARNING: File 'C:\agent\_work\1\s\Services\Internal\Credit.Internal.Api\Properties\PublishProfiles\api-credit-uat - FTP.pubxml' does not exist.
11:17:30.715  11:17:30.715  WARNING: File 'C:\agent\_work\1\s\Services\Internal\Credit.Internal.Api\Properties\PublishProfiles\api-credit-uat - ReadOnly - FTP.pubxml' does not exist.
Calling the TFS Processor executable...
Fetching code coverage report information from TFS...
Attempting to locate a test results (.trx) file...
Looking for TRX files in: C:\agent\_work\1\TestResults
The following test results files were found: C:\agent\_work\1\TestResults\agentdevopsvm1$_agentdevopsvm1_2024-07-22_11_15_24.trx
**No code coverage attachments were found from the trx files.**
Not using the fallback mechanism to detect binary coverage files.
Coverage report conversion completed successfully.

Below is the yaml file I have configired
    trigger:
    - feature/EE-14
    
    pool:
      name: DevOpsAgent
      
    
    variables:
    - name: BuildConfiguration
      value: Dev
    - name: BuildPlatform
      value: any cpu
    
    jobs:
    - job: Job_1
      displayName: Code Quality Job
       
    
      steps:
      - checkout: self
        clean: true
        fetchTags: false
      - task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
        inputs:
          packageFeedSelector: 'nugetOrg'
          versionSelector: 'latestStable'
      - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
        displayName: NuGet install
        inputs:
          versionSpec: 6.6.1
    
      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        displayName: NuGet Restore
        inputs:
          command: restore
          includeSymbols: false
          includeNuGetOrg: true
          restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
          
      
      - task: UseDotNet@2
        inputs:
          packageType: 'runtime'
          version: '3.1.0'
          installationPath: C:\Program Files\dotnet\
    
      - task: SonarCloudPrepare@2
        displayName: Prepare Sonar Cloud Analysis
        inputs:
          SonarCloud: '********'
          organization: '*******'
          scannerMode: 'MSBuild'
          projectKey: '*******'
          projectName: '*****'
         
    
      - task: VSBuild@1
        displayName: Build Solution
        retryCountOnTaskFailure: 1
        inputs:
          vsVersion: latest
          platform: $(BuildPlatform)
          configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)
          clean: true
      
      - task: VSTest@2
        displayName: Run Tests
        inputs:
          testAssemblyVer2: |
           Tests\Functional\*.*[Tt]ests\**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*[Tt]ests*.dll
           Tests\Functional\*.*[Tt]ests\**\$(BuildConfiguration)\net6.0\*[Tt]ests*.dll
           Tests\Functional\*.*[Tt]ests\**\$(BuildConfiguration)\netcoreapp3.1\*[Tt]ests*.dll
           !**\*dMVC.Tests.Common*
           !**\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform*
           !**\obj\**
          platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
          configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
          runInParallel: true 
          pathtoCustomTestAdapters: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\packages
          resultsFolder: 'C:\agent\_work\1\TestResults'
          codeCoverageEnabled: true
          # customCoverletOptions: '--format cobertura'  # Example for .NET Core with Coverlet
          diagnosticsEnabled: true
          
      - task: SonarCloudAnalyze@2
        displayName: Run Code Analysis
        inputs:
          jdkversion: 'JAVA_HOME_17_X64'
    
      - task: SonarCloudPublish@2
        inputs:
          pollingTimeoutSec: '300'

Project file:
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
      </PropertyGroup>
    
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.8.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.14.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.5.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.9.0">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Refit.HttpClientFactory" Version="6.3.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
      </ItemGroup>
    
      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Services\Shared\Credit.Internal.Api.Client\Credit.Internal.Api.Client.csproj" />
      </ItemGroup>
    
      <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="Resources\blank.pdf">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
      </ItemGroup>
    
    </Project>


The error message looks strange, like a mixture of SonarCloudPrepare@2 and  SonarCloudAnalyze@2, could you please clarify which task did the error report? Please also give a try with Microsoft-Hosted agent.

@wadezhou-MSFT The error is from SonarCloudAnalyze@2

Looks like the actual issue is when running vs test we are getting the error
Data collection : Unable to find a datacollector with friendly name 'Code Coverage'.

Thanks for the update. You can check vsts test task for result trx and coverage report. Make sure they are generated correctly, then analysis task can find them. Please check the detail below. thanks.

As per the error message, the test result trx was found but not for coverage report. You can confirm the VSTest@2 task result for both files, make sure they are generated correctly.

My Vsts task for your reference. Use $(Agent.BuildDirectory)\TestResults for the resultsFolder:
  - task: VSTest@2
    inputs:
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: |
        **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*Test*.dll
        !**\*dMVC.Tests.Common*
        !**\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform*
        !**\obj\**
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      resultsFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\TestResults'
      runInParallel: true
      codeCoverageEnabled: true
      platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
      diagnosticsEnabled: true

And SonarCloudAnalyze@2 can find the trx and coverage report successfully.

Edit:
I can reproduce the same problem(Data collection : Unable to find a datacollector with friendly name 'Code Coverage'.) with self-hosted agent. It's fixed by changing to visual studio enterprise edition, as coverage is only available on this edition.



I think am missing something on the self hosted agent, because if i use the Microsoft hosted agent both files are generated but on the self hosted agent only the trx is created and not the coverage file. What could that be?

What edition of visual studio installed on your self-hosted agent? coverage is only  available in Visual Studio Enterprise, please check the link for the test tool difference between editions.

I can reproduce the same problem with self-hosted agent, after i change to install Visual studio enterprise edition, coverage can be generated, it fixed for me. I will edit the reply with details.

Thanks, the Visual studio version was the issue
